# How to pass data to UITabBarController?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, xcode8

How do I pass data from `UIViewController` to one of the `UIViewController`'s inside `UITabBarController`?

The following didn't work:

```
let hospitalsController = segue.destination as! postRequest
hospitalsController.hospitalName = "Hospital Name"
```

when trying above code, I get the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x10d05f418) to 'ProjectName.postRequest' (0x10b17fdd0).
```

when I tried the following:

```
let test = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
            let test2 = test.topViewController as! postRequest
            test2.hospitalName = "Khola Hospital"
```

The app crashed with no error,

when I tried to print `print(tabBarController?.viewControllers)` it showed me `nil` in the console

What is the correct way to pass data from `UIViewController` to one of the `UIViewControllers` inside `UITabBarController`?

**UPDATE**
Here is my main storyboard
[image: StoryBoard]

The data is to be passed from he top `UIViewController` to the bottom right `UIViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are too closed to make it work only one mistake you need to cast `segue.destination` to `UITabBarController` and you all set to go.

```
if let tabbarController = segue.destination as? UITabBarController, 
   let postVC = tabbarController.viewControllers?.first as? postRequest, 

     postVC.hospitalName = "Khola Hospital"
}
```

Comment: the app doesn't crash but the value is not passed to hospitalName. It shows nil in the console

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi There is not navigation Controller check the edited answer, if it still not work then change `first` with `last`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! and sorry for my silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom `UITabBarController` class and pass the data to that `tabBarController` and then in your desired `ViewController` where you want to get hospital name just check the availability of `tabBarController` and fetch the hospital name

```
class YourCustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    var hospitalName = ""
    //Do You Other Work Below
}

class PostRequest: UIViewController {
    var hospitalName = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let tabBarVC = self.tabBarController as? YourCustomTabBarController {
            self.hospitalName = tabBarVC.hospitalName
        }
        //Handle Other Work.
    }
}


if let tabBarVC = segue.destination as? YourCustomTabBarController {
    tabBarVC.hospitalName = "XYZ Hospital"
}
```