# How to pass data from one UIViewController to another?

Tags: swift, uikit

I have UITabViewController and two UIViewControllers. I use storyboards and segues. In the first VC.
I get data from Firebase and save it. Then I need to pass this data to another vc in order to change the text of UILabel in the second vc.
Thank you

```
func fetchCeloriesData() {
        refWorkout = workout!.title
         Database.database().reference().child("programs").child(refWorkout).child("calories").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            let caloriesData = snapshot.value as! String
            print(caloriesData)
            
           
           // self.dietVC.BurnedLabel.text? = caloriesData
             
         }
     }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best way, but for simple data like Int/String I use Userdefaults, while for objects I call in the VC where I want the data to be passed something like: VC1().dataINeedToPass and I assign it to a new variable

Comment: If I don't misunderstand, this might be what you want -> [How to pass data to UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44180862/11593936)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards and segues, you can simply use

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, 
  sender: Any?)
```

you can identify segue there from storyboard and sender will be self.
and then

```
func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
       sender: Any?)
```

Here you have to take identifier from storyboard which will be string. and on the event of moving to second ViewController call this perfromSegue function.